# Deploying springboot app and ui separately

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Currently, I have a springboot jar file with a bunch of rest and apis including calls for login deployed on ec2. I also have a separate code base for my ui i.e with js,html,css. What is the best way to deploy this on aws and keep it separate from the backend.

Comment: Deploy your application in a single EC2 or using Elasticbeanstalk which handles the autoscaling and loadbalancer parts also. Then deploy your frontend in S3 bucket, which saves you cost.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways. But will share a simple way.

Deploy your spring boot app in one aws instance.
Deploy the other front end app on the other aws instance.

This is a kind of  two tier application where the server and client app are  hosted in different instance. You can restrict the access of your rest api to be accessed only by the instance where you host front end app. For trial you can use heroku account. E.g.

Github: https://github.com/krishna28/springbootapi
Also check https://github.com/krishna28/etodo

Comment: Then how do u manage login. Do u route to the other instance with creds and send somekind of a token to authorize each request?

Comment: Since it's a two tier application, token is used for authentication and authorization. The token is send as a part of header on every request. HTTP interceptors can be used to send token with every request. I have user angularjs http interceptors for handling this.

Comment: No i meant for external users who want to login to the application. Like currently in my local i authenticate using ldap setup. So i was thinking of installing apacheds on ec2 and manage login using that. Is that a good approach or should i using something else to manage user creds